# Do I need to install Windows Embedded CE 6.0 before installing R3?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I need to install the Windows Embedded CE development tools on my system. Right now I am using Windows XP SP2.

I have the installers for Windows Embedded CE 6.0, and Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3 and R2 editions.

I don't know which ones I need to install, and which order I need to install them in.

How can I successfully install it?  Also, is it supported in Windows 7?

Comment: This actually is programming related.  They are asking about the toolchain for creating the OS, kernel and drivers and what OS supports the toolchain

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you face a question like this, you need to start by *reading [the download details](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=BC247D88-DDB6-4D4A-A595-8EEE3556FE46&displaylang=en)* that MS provides:

> - **Supported Operating Systems:** Windows CE Windows Vista, Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, Windows XP Service Pack 3
>
> ...
>
> - **Required Software:**
>
>   - Windows Embedded CE 6.0
>   - Visual Studio 2005 (except Express)
>   - Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1
>   - Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista (if applicable)
>   - Windows Embedded CE 6.0 SP1 (required if PB 6.0 Tools have been installed)
>   - Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R2

So **there's your answer**: You need to install CE 6.0, then CE 6.0 R2, and finally CE 6.0 R3. And Windows 7 is *not* supported... But Vista is, so you *might* be able to get away with it anyway; if not, you could try the [XP Mode VM](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode) available for Windows 7 Professional edition.